# Programming Pattern: What is irregular loop?

Tags: compilation, cuda

I read from the Kepler architecture tech brief that **dynamic parallelism**, newly added in *CUDA 5.0*, supports *recursion* and *irregular loop structure* in programming patterns.

But could anybody tell me what *irregular loop structure* is?

Comment: According to my best guess, it means that you don't know the number of iterations in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this book on page 146](http://books.google.com/books?id=YbmaKee9c-kC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=%22irregular%20loop%20structure%22&source=bl&ots=mDyhLa_JEk&sig=kUb7OTjGIcOzHR-_WvUdJC4X3cU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EXAvUa2qLZTY9ASVioH4Dw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=irregular&f=false) , (which is specifically addressing implementing kernels),

> A regular loop has a definite number of iterations, while the number of iterations of an irregular loop depends on certain conditions.

They also provide some examples here:

**Regular loop**

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //...;
}
```

**Irregular loop**

```
while (i < 0)
{
    if (con) 
       {i--;}
    else
        //...;
        i++;
}
```

**Another Irregular loop**

```
while (true)
{
    if (cond1) 
        {break;}
    else
    {
        //...;
        if (cond2)
            {break;}
    }
}
```

Just to be clear, support for irregular loops within a kernel has always existed.  Instead, they are suggesting that in CUDA 5.0 you can now write GPU code that more closely mimics recursive or irregularly looping **algorithms** by using the dynamic parallelism feature.  Used correctly, this feature could allow you to implement solutions that avoid warp divergence by launching child kernels.

Comment: I still don't understand how **dynamic parallel** enables GPU code to more closely mimic **irregular loop**. Could you please explain it further?